# using gsub to remove strings but not numeric

Tags: r, gsub

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
 id   col1
  1     4
  2     -
  3     +
  4     _
  5     N
  6     text-abc
  7     50
```

I am aiming to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 id   col1
  1     4
  2     0
  3     0
  4     0
  5     0
  6     0
  7     50
```

I want to keep the numeric values the way they are and convert the "-", "+", "_", "N", and "text-abc" into zeros. That is, I'd only like numeric values to be in this column, convert texts and other strings into zeros and leave the numeric values as they are. This is a very long column (ie thousands of rows) and may contain other unneccessary text.

To fix, I tried to do it manually by using the following:

```
  df$col1 <- gsub("text-abc", 0, df$col1)
  df$col1 <- gsub("+", 0, df$col1)
  df$col1 <- gsub("-", 0, df$col1)
  df$col1 <- gsub("_", 0, df$col1)
  df$col1 <- gsub("N", 0, df$col1)
```

However, as mentioned, this is not practical for large sets of data. As such, I tried the following:

```
  df$col1 <- gsub("[^[[:alnum:]]", 0, df$col1)
```

But it simply changed "text-abc" to "text0abc" instead of turning the whole thing into 0. Ideally, I'd like the column to only contain numeric values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance for your time!

Comment: Silly me. Thank you so much Ronak!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of converting column on case by case basis, we can use `as.numeric` to change non-numeric column to `NA`s and then convert those `NA`'s to 0.

```
df$col1 <- as.numeric(df$col1)

#Use this if `col1` is factor
#df$col1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$col1))

df$col1[is.na(df$col1)] <- 0

df

#  id col1
#1  1    4
#2  2    0
#3  3    0
#4  4    0
#5  5    0
#6  6    0
#7  7   50
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use regex to do this

```
df$col1[!grepl('^[0-9]+$', df$col1)] <- 0
df$col1 <- as.numeric(df$col1)
df
#  id col1
#1  1    4
#2  2    0
#3  3    0
#4  4    0
#5  5    0
#6  6    0
#7  7   50
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:7, col1 = c("4", "-", "+", "_", "N", "text-abc", 
   "50")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```